# Proving a claim about the decomposition of a fraction

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers that are coprime and such that $b > 4$ is composite. Prove or disprove the following: There are integers $k, a_1,\cdots, a_{b-1}$ with $0\leq a_i\leq i-1$ for $i=1,\cdots, b-1$ so that $\frac{a}b = k + \sum_{i=1}^{b-1} \frac{a_i}{i!}$. In addition, determine with proof whether the integers $k,a_1,\cdots, a_{b-1}$ are unique.

Note that a counterexample for $b=4$ is the following: $\frac{1}4 \neq \frac{a_2}{2} + \frac{a_3}{6}$ for any $0\leq a_2\leq 1, 0\leq a_3\leq 2$, so it's definitely important that $b > 4$ (if the claim is true that is).

I think the claim is true, but I'm not sure how to prove it. Below is what I've done so far.

I know that since $a$ and $b$ are coprime, by Bezout's theorem, there exist integers $x,y$ so that $ax+by = 1$. I also know that each positive integer has a unique factorial-base representation, though I'm not sure how to prove this. That is, for a positive integer $a$, there is a unique way to write $a$ in the form $\sum_{j=1}^n f_j \cdot j!$ where for all $j, 0\leq f_j \leq j$. Since $b$ is composite, there are positive integers $c,d$ with $1<c\leq d < b$ so that $b=cd$. The statement is equivalent to defining the $a_i$'s so that $\frac{a}b - \sum_{i=1}^{b-1} \frac{a_i}{i!}$ is an integer, which implies that $a\prod_{i=1}^{b-1} (i!) - b\sum_{i=1}^{b-1} a_i \prod_{1\leq k\leq b-1, k\neq i} k!$ must be divisible by $b\prod_{i=1}^{b-1}(i!)$, but this seems too complicated to work with. Assume $\frac{a}b$ is not an integer; otherwise the statement trivially holds. One can write $\frac{a}{b} = q+r$ where $0\leq r < 1, q \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.

Comment: What a nice result! See the proof below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first need the following result.

**Any non-negative integer up to $n!-1$ can be expressed as
$$n!(\frac{a_n}{n!}+\frac{a_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+ ... \frac{a_2}{2!}),$$
where $0\le a_i\le i-1.$**

To prove this let the integer be $xn+y$ where $0\le y\le n-1 $ and then set $a_n=y$.
We then require $$x=(n-1)!(\frac{a_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+\frac{a_{n-2}}{(n-2)!}+ ... \frac{a_2}{2!}),$$ where $0\le x<(n-1)!$ Repeating this process as necessary gives us the necessary expansion.

**Proof of your conjecture**

Now consider the fraction $\frac{a}{b}$. By subtracting an integer we can suppose that $a<b$. Since $b$ is composite there is a factorial $n!$ with $n<b$ such that $\frac{an!}{b}$ is an integer. (Note that this is false for $b=4$.)

Now express $\frac{an!}{b}$ as $n!(\frac{a_n}{n!}+\frac{a_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+ ... \frac{a_2}{2!})$ and then divide by $n!$